# Locally save SqlCredential file with powershell - SQL connection

Tags: sql, powershell, credentials

I want to connect to a SQL database with powershell using a **credential file.**

To create my credential file, I simply used :

```
$Credential = Get-Credential
$Credential | Export-CliXml -Path "mypath\sql.cred"
```

Then I run :

```
$ServerInstance = 'myserverinstance.net'
$Database = 'myDB'
$cred = Import-CliXml -Path "mypath\sql.cred"

$conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$conn.ConnectionString = "Server=$ServerInstance; Database=$Database;"
$conn.Credential = $cred
$conn.Open()
```

I got the following error :

> Exception setting "Credential": "Cannot convert the
> "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential" value of type
> "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential" to  type
> "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCredential"."

How to create a Sql credential file (that I can save locally on my computer) so that my scrip can work ?

Comment: For obvious security reasions, credentials can only be decripted under the same account as they have been encrypted. It looks like you trying to build some [Security through obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity), instead you should use different accounts (or authentication) at your database side.

Comment: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Credential does not take a PSCredential directly.  You need to create a SqlCredential object from the values of PSCredential. `$cred.Password.MakeReadOnly(); $conn.Credential = [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCredential]::new($cred.UserName, $cred.Password)`.  Also, what iRon said.  Importing the clixml will only work if you are using the same windows account that you created it with on the same computer.

Comment: One more thing is the windows user's password must also be the same. `PSCredential` objects are literally encrypted with your current username+password, so if you change your password, then you will not be able to import the credentials anymore. These days, a better option is usually through the `CredentialManager` module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Credential` does not take a `System.Management.Automation.PSCredential` directly. You need to create a SqlCredential object from the values of PSCredential.

```
$cred.Password.MakeReadOnly()
$conn.Credential = [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCredential]::new($cred.UserName, $cred.Password)
```